# Create External Hive table using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am trying to create an external hive table using spark. But facing below error:

```
 using Create but with is expecting
```

Comment: Can you share the code and exact error

Answer (score 2):

Use of location implies that a created table via Spark it will be treated as an external table.

From the manual: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html. You can also reference this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html

> **LOCATION**
>
> The created table uses the specified directory to store its data. This
>   clause automatically implies EXTERNAL.

More explicitly:

```
// Prepare a Parquet data directory
val dataDir = "/tmp/parquet_data"
spark.range(10).write.parquet(dataDir)
// Create a Hive external Parquet table
sql(s"CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_bigints(id bigint) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '$dataDir'")
// The Hive external table should already have data
sql("SELECT * FROM hive_bigints").show()
```

Also, has nothing to do with pyspark.

If using spark dataframe writer, then the option "path" used below means unmanaged and thus external as well.

```
df.write.mode("OVERWRITE").option("path", unmanagedPath).saveAsTable("myTableUnmanaged")
```